# How to add number of retries and retry interval in seconds in Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz's `JDBCJobStore`. I added job details, trigger information into tables using `CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule()`. **if any scheduled job fails, I need it to be retried given a number of retries and retry interval**. So, how can I add those parameters into table for a job?

Comment: Have You tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware , Quartz has no way of doing this. You will have to manage it yourselves.

> if any job scheduler fails

I presume that above line is pointing to failure of any scheduled job. 
As soon as, the trigger fires the associated job starts running. So, there are 2 possibilities of failure here.

- Scheduler is made hard shutdown when the job is being executed.

Quartz can handle this at its best. We have request-recovery attribute set for every job.
IF set to true, we are telling quartz that, "Recover/rerun this job at scheduler next startup if scheduler is hard shutdown during its execution". More information on this attribute [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03).

- The job has thrown an exception during its execution.

This might means in our business logic that it has failed.( Note : Quartz don't assume this job as failed. You will have to decide this in your lifecycle of job that it has failed because of this exception.)

You can handle this by including all the code in job's exeucute() method in a try/catch block.
If any critical exception occured, inside catch block we will  handle it in a way that we want to re-schedule the job again( i.e. making the job to retry again ).

So, For this you can always create a new jobdetail and trigger ( by using some of the parameters in jobExecutionContext of failed job) to recreate/reschedule the job again .